# Back button of Adobe PDF Reader after clicking a hyperlink whose target is on the same document

Tags: browser, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf

PDF documents have hyperlinks to the contents on the same document (analogous to "#section" hrefs for an HTML document). Where's the back button to go back to the page I was on (where I clicked the hyperlink).

Let's say I'm on the index of a PDF tutorial, page 4, and I click on Chapter 2's hyperlink in the index that takes me to page 38. Now, if I want to go back to page 4 again, which button or shortcut should I use?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I have always had luck using the combination Alt and the left arrow, much the same as in IE, Firefox, or any other browser. I found this out on accident when I was in a PDF document in a browser and found it worked in the standalone program as well.

On the Mac, the equivalent in Adobe Reader is command-left arrow. In Preview (the default PDF reader on Macs), the equivalent is command-[ (open square bracket).

Comment: Doesn't work for evince :(

Comment: Works for FoxIt Reader 6.1

Comment: not work on Acrobat reader in Chrome browser.

Comment: nice, works fine in win pdf

Comment: Okular has this as well. Default shortcut is alt+shift+left, but you can change it to alt+left

Comment: In Preview, you can also add navigation buttons to the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for for months

Comment: does not work in google chrome's pdf viewer...

Answer (score 32):

"Back" and "Forward" buttons can also be added to the toolbar in Adobe Reader.  If you right-click on the tool bar, under "more tools," "page navigation toolbar," they are referred to as "previous view" and "next view."

Or alternatively:  Click on the VIEW drop down menu , then Click PAGE NAVIGATION then click PREVIOUS VIEW.  A backward arrow will then appear in the toolbar at the top.  Repeat for NEXT VIEW to add a forward arrow.

Comment: These aren't really "back" and "forward" buttons as you would expect from a browser. If you hit pagedown 100 times, the "back" button will take you back through each one of those 100 locations.

Answer (score 5):

### For Foxit users,

As stated in the other answers you can use [alt + left arrow] as a shortcut.

If you want see this on the menu

- Open Foxit
- Go View tab
- You can see on top left corner of the windows, previous view-next view

Comment: Perfect saved me! It works on the latest Adobe Acrobat Reader Version .

Answer (score 4):

In Evince you can use the Back Button functionality to achieve what you desire.

The Back Button is not visible by default, but you can make it visible by the following steps.

- Right-Click on ToolBar
- Selct Toolbar, from the Context Menu.
- In the Window that appears, Drag and Drop the Back Buttton to your Toolbar.

**Note**:
The Back functionality is not similar to what you get in a browser. When you press Back, it gives a list of all the links you had visited in that Document and you can select from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Its already mentioned in adobe acrobat
go to view->page navigation->previous view (hot keys alt+left arrow)
go to view->page navigation->next view (hot keys alt+fwd arrow)

Answer (score 2):

For **okular**, the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.
This can be configured as per user liking through

> Settings >> Configure Shortcuts

Comment: What is okular?

Comment: [More than a reader](https://okular.kde.org/)  
This is a default PDF reader in KDE.

Answer (score 2):

**Move back to previously opened topic**

Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

Mac    : <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

**Move forward to next topic**

Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Mac    : <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

These are all the Keyboard shortcuts that [Adobe Acrobat supports](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Comment: Works on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

See the other answers for keyboard shortcuts that work on desktops and laptops but these are not generally available on tablets.  On iPad, none of the big-name PDF readers have a back button, including Apple, Adobe ond Foxit.  Adobe's "Previous View" feature on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> is not available on its mobile versions.

[PDF Reader Pro](https://www.pdfreaderpro.com/), including the free Lite Edition, has Android and iOS versions that do have a back button.  It appears as a left arrow on the lower right corner of the screen immediately after a link has been followed.  Touching the arrow returns to your previous view.  Unfortunately it only works for one level so following two links consecutively gives you no quick way to go back to the original page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128529)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the links to a new window, then you just have to close the file to display the previous.

To do this:

1. Open the link ***Properties*** sheet.
2. Click the ***Actions*** tab.
3. Click the ***Edit*** button.
4. Change the ***Target Document***, ***Open In*** property to ***New Window***.
5. Click ***OK*** twice.

Answer (score 0):

For Foxit reader:

- Mac: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently, for previous visited page it is Alt + p. For the next page, it is Alt + n.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202218/how-to-go-back-to-last-page-viewed-in-document-viewer